# Spoofing a Paypal Hosted Page Silent Post

Tags: security, post, paypal

I am building out a registration system using PayPal Hosted Pages. From what I understand I can use the Silent POST feature to let my application know when a successful transaction has occurred on the hosted checkout page. I worry that it will be possible to spoof this POST request and manipulate my application into thinking a transaction was successful.

Example:

When a user checks out they are redirected to a URL like

```
https://payflowlink.paypal.com/?MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID=XXX&SECURETOKEN=YYY
```

They can copy `XXX` and `YYY` and use an application like cURL to send a POST request to my application endpoint, thus tricking into thinking there was a successful transaction.

Is there a preferred method of securely handling silent POST requests to prevent this scenario? Is there a better method altogether of notifying my application of a successful transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a userid/and matching secure key as well as a date stamp, that way, only a random generated secure key, and a user id can be used, for a given time frame (usually couple minutes)...

Comment: Not a bad idea but is this really what PayPal had in mind when they were planning out this service? It seems like they would have a sample or recommended implementation somewhere.